# Are return statements bad in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, return

The return keyword is optional in ruby so for functions with only one exit point, "return result" can be safely replaced with simply "result".

Is there any Ruby-specific guidelines to when to do this?

I tend to avoid the return keyword as much as possible due to their unruly behavior in procs.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

"return" in ruby is only used if you are trying to return more than one value. e.g.

```
return val1, val2
```

or if it makes sense to return earlier from a function e.g.

```
#check if needed param is set
return if !param

#some operations which need param
```

which is easier than messing your code up with cascaded if-statements.

Conclusion: Use return every time it simplifies your code or it makes it easier to understand.

Comment: are you sure about the first point? *def fun; [val1, val2]; end* The second one is ok.

Comment: yep. if you return multiple values as array (as you described) you will not be able to receive the values with val1,val2=fun. You would have to do ret=fun; val1=ret[0]; val2=ret[1] to achive the same.

Comment: sorry to insist, but it doesn't matter if are using return or not, you are returning an array (which later you can unpack) *def fun; [1, 2]; end; a, b = fun; "a=#{a}, b=#{b}"* #=> "a=1, b=2"

Comment: Ok. So does that mean I should drop return in all other cases? eg "def f; result=0; #some-complex-code; result;" as opposed to "...return result;"?

Comment: @tokland: you are right, it is also possible to use that one. But it is much overhead because you are creating an array-instance each time you return something. @alexoh: it's common style in ruby to not use return in all other cases

Comment: @k_wave Isn't an array implicitly created with return v1,v2 ?